# Example where the closure of a point does not contain a closed point in a Nonnoetherian Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, noetherian

Let $x\in X$ be a point of a Noetherian scheme. Then the closure of $x$ contains a closed point. 
Is there an example in non-Noetherian schemes where this property does not hold?

Comment: You can proceed locally (in a ring), where this is clear (a commutative ring have a maximal ideal).

Comment: You can take any scheme that has no closed points (e.g., §4 in [this article by Karl Schwede](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/schwede03.pdf), or [Liu, Excs. 3.3.26, 3.3.27]).